# The APK size becomes too big when I only modify a small number of code lines

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The APK is generated by Android Studio. I find that the APK size becomes significantly large when I only modify a small part of my code. [image]

Shown as in the picture (APK named old is the one I refer to as the "new APK"). And when I unzip the new APK, I find that the total size of all unzipped files is similar to the size of the APK.

How did this happen? I changed the gradle version to 5.6.4 recently.

Comment: look at this : https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e

Answer (score 0):

APK files are actually zip files, and there are different ways to compress the same information. Some compressors notice equal files, some do not. I believe this is the case that you have. The old compressor did not optimize for repeating files, and the new compressor does.

Answer (score 0):

You have some large libraries (maybe you've imported .jar files manually).
Make sure you use all of them . otherwise delete unused libraries and `Clean` and `Rebuild` your project.